# Want the list of languages supported by each font.Is there any open source font library or database listing them?

Tags: javascript, webfont-loader

I want the list of languages supported by each font.Is there any open source library or database listing them? Alternatively, Apple Font Book  list of languages supported by the font. How is it generated? I assume there is some internal database. Is there any way to extract it?

Answer (score 0):

The [Unicode Common Locale Data Rpository (CLDR)](http://cldr.unicode.org/index) contains [a fairly extensive compilation of "Examplars"](http://www.unicode.org/cldr/charts/by_type/misc.exemplarCharacters.html), which are the minimum support required for various languages. Although Font Book is not specifically listed as one of the applications, the CLDR index page does mention Apple as a company that uses it, and it's very likely that's what Font Book employs to determine language support.

Note though that in many cases, simply having the *characters* is not enough for full language/script support. For many writing systems, additional characters and font data (OpenType Layout data) are required.